# Apply Apache httpd configuration to exact file and no subdirectories

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

I have a problem that it seems should be simple.  I want to apply a group of configuration directives to a single file (in this case `myfile.html` in the DocumentRoot).  There may also be subdirectories containing `myfile.html`, these should *not* get the configuration.  I also want to do it *without* using `Location` or `LocationMatch`.

I came up with the following

```
DocumentRoot "/home/amoe/opt/httpd/htdocs"
<DirectoryMatch "^/home/amoe/opt/httpd/htdocs$">
    <Files "myfile.html">
        ExpiresActive on
        ExpiresDefault A10
    </Files>
</DirectoryMatch>
```

However, the `Expires` header doesn't get set when requesting `/myfile.html`.  Adding a trailing slash on the `DirectoryMatch` seems to make no difference.

You can assume that I want to do this without `Location` for academic reasons.  (Edit: Also, to quote the documentation, *It is important to never use  when trying to restrict access to objects in the filesystem.*)

Comment: Have you tried using .htaccess files in each directory you need to modify the settings?

Comment: @Gmck I also don't want to use `.htaccess` -- again it's a personal preference but I find it makes things difficult to manage.

Comment: Are you opposed to using a configuration management system like Salt or Chef?  This type of tool can make file management and placement in this sort of scenario easier.

Comment: @Matt I already use configuration management but it seems to me that `.htaccess` should not be required for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I have found to make this work is by using the following:

```
<DirectoryMatch ^/home/amoe/opt/httpd/htdocs/[^/]+$>
    <Files "test.html">
        ExpiresActive on
        ExpiresDefault A10
    </Files>
</DirectoryMatch>
```

I believe that the extra `[^/]+` shouldn't be required to get this to work, see below for the full explanation of how I came to this conclusion, and as such I believe this is a bug in Apache.

---

All of the following is based on an Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS environment running Apache 2.4.23 with test files in these locations:

- `/path/test/test.html`
- `/path/test/noheader-test.html`
- `/path/test/child/test.html`
- `/path/test/child/grandchild/test.html`

Firstly I tried a number of different regex variants, all of which failed to match:

```
<DirectoryMatch ^/path/test$>
<DirectoryMatch ^/path/test/$>
<DirectoryMatch /path/test/$>
<Directory ~ ^/path/test$>
<Directory ~ ^/path/test/$>
<Directory ~ /path/test/$>
```

I found however that if you omit the EOL anchor (`$`) then it matches:

```
<DirectoryMatch ^/path/test/>
    <Files "test.html">
        ExpiresActive on
        ExpiresDefault A10
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

However this ofcourse matches the `test.html` files in all the subdirectories:

- `/path/test/test.html` - **Expires header sent**
- `/path/test/noheader-test.html` - no Expires header sent
- `/path/test/child/test.html` - **Expires header sent**
- `/path/test/child/grandchild/test.html` - **Expires header sent**

It was as though there was something else in the path that the regex wasn't matching because when I changed the regex to `^/your/path/test/.+$` it matched.

Wanting to know what this missing part of the path was I used a regex capture group and the `Header` directive to get Apache to tell me what was missing, like so:

```
<DirectoryMatch ^/path/test/(?<MISSINGPART>.+)$>
    <Files "test.html">
        Header add X-TEST "expr=%{env:MATCH_MISSINGPART}"
    </Files>
</DirectoryMatch>
```

This gave the following headers:

- `/path/test/test.html` - `x-test:"test.html"`
- `/path/test/noheader-test.html` - no header sent
- `/path/test/child/test.html` - `x-test:"child/test.html"`
- `/path/test/child/grandchild/test.html` - `x-test:"child/grandchild/test.html"`

This suggests that `DirectoryMatch` is matching the file name too?!

On the Apache bug tracker [bug 41867](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41867) somewhat fits this description so may explain this (I also tested this without the nested `<Files>` directive and the header values remained the same)

So to prove it I tried substituting `test.html` into the regex like so:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/path/test/test.html$">
    <Files "test.html">
        Header add X-TEST "Match"
    </Files>
</DirectoryMatch>
```

No `X-TEST` header was returned.

This did however mean that the regex could be made to match anything that isn't a directory after the directory we're interested in matching, like so:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/path/test/[^/]+$">
    <Files "test.html">
        ExpiresActive on
        ExpiresDefault A10
    </Files>
</DirectoryMatch>
```

This gives the header in all the desired places:

- `/path/test/test.html` - **Expires header sent**
- `/path/test/noheader-test.html` - no Expires header sent
- `/path/test/child/test.html` - no Expires header sent
- `/path/test/child/grandchild/test.html` - no Expires header sent